# How to print log level with easy_init in Log4perl?

Tags: perl, log4perl

I sorely miss information on the log level of every line in Log4perl's `easy_init`. I'm running a large migration script which fails at some special records, so I need to grep for `WARN`ings and `ERROR`s, but need the `INFO`rmation context to fix those.

Using this code:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict; use warnings;
use Log::Log4perl qw(:easy);

Log::Log4perl->easy_init($INFO);

TRACE "bar";
DEBUG "baz";
INFO  "qux";
WARN  "quux";
ERROR "corge";
FATAL "grault";
```

Right now, I get this output:

```
2013/06/02 13:08:48 qux
2013/06/02 13:08:48 quux
2013/06/02 13:08:48 corge
2013/06/02 13:08:48 grault
```

I do not want to add this information in the log message, as it's already included in which log function I call.

How to add the log level with `easy_init`? I do not want to initialize the "regular" Log4perl with a configuration file (even if included inline) in a rather small script and I like `easy_init` for its clear and brief usage.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`easy_init` also accepts hashes as parameters, which enable extended configuration, for example log files and the layout. `%-5p` will print the log level, left-aligned to five characters.

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict; use warnings;
use Log::Log4perl qw(:easy);

Log::Log4perl->easy_init({
    level   => $INFO,
    layout  => '%d %-5p %m%n'
});

TRACE "bar";
DEBUG "baz";
INFO  "qux";
WARN  "quux";
ERROR "corge";
FATAL "grault";
```

Output will now be

```
2013/06/02 13:08:56 INFO  qux
2013/06/02 13:08:56 WARN  quux
2013/06/02 13:08:56 ERROR corge
2013/06/02 13:08:56 FATAL grault
```

For further placeholders, have a look at [Log4perl's PatternLayout documentation](https://metacpan.org/module/Log%3a%3aLog4perl%3a%3aLayout%3a%3aPatternLayout#DESCRIPTION).